# Android reading JsonObject from php as a string

Tags: php, android, json

I want to get my json result from my php and display it in android, I tried many solutions and nothing is working for me. In android side I used JSONParser and always I get json = null in this ligne `JSONObject json=jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);` with this error: `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value n of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

I will post my php code because my android code I am sure it is working since I tested it with another php code using codeigniter framework.

```
function get_user($id = 0) {
  global $connection;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
  if ($id != 0) {
    $query. = "WHERE id =".$id. "LIMIT 1";
  }
  $response = array();
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($response, array("id" => $row['id'], "username" => $row['username']));
  }
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array('user' => $response));
  mysli_close($connection);
}
```

the result while executing my url is :

```
{
  "user": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "username": "myusername"

    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The JSON looks fine. The issue rests in how your Java code is processing it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is the problem I can't understand where is the problem because I have the same function using codeigniter and give me the same json result. The url from codeigniter is working fine when this one I get this error Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value n of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Your line `$query= "SELECT * FROM users;` is missing a `"`.  Also `mysqli+query`?

Comment: Wow, there are so many typos in here, it would throw a lot of errors. Can you please post the exact code?

Comment: ^^^ What @NigelRen said. If that is your real PHP code then it is failing miserably and producing errors.

Comment: Sorry I copied it wrong. But it is correct in my file like you have mentionned since it gives me the result

Comment: When you fail at even a simple copy+paste then it makes it hard to believe that anything in your post is truthful.

Comment: In your Java code you should get the URL's output as a string and check to make sure it is what you expect; do not immediately try to parse it as JSON. This is the most basic of debugging techniques.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make a copy paste since my code is in cloud server I just rewrite it. Now I edited it.

Comment: Anyways, if Java is throwing the error then Java needs to tell you why. Your debugging start point should be in Java. If Java reveals a PHP issue then pursue PHP.

Comment: I debugged it and it gives me a null value for my json variable. I will try to get my URL output as a string

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it is the same problem, I get my URL output as a string and the string variable gives me null value

Comment: I don't know enough about Java to hold you hand through this but it sounds like Java cannot reach your URL to retrieve the JSON.